# Processing a large list of strings

Tags: c#, performance, regex, wpf

I am working on an application in C# WPF which reads a large file containing a number of HL7 formatted reports. My application takes in the file, reads and extracts any lines that starts with OBX and stores it into a List. It then tries to extract report headers from the each line, if one exists, based on a handle-full of rules:

1. Ends with a ':'
2. Is in all caps
3. Is less then 6 words (not include words in brackets)
4. Contains more 4 characters
5. May be on its own in a line or embedded into the content of the string (always at the start)

I have the algorithm down and it works, but I am dealing with files which can contain an upward of a million lines. My initial design took about 10-15 minutes to read and process around 1 million lines. Through hours of research, I was able to optimize the code a bit, bring it to about a few minutes. However, I am hoping to optimize it even further in order to reduce the time it takes for the app to process the lines. This is where I need some help as I do not know what I can do further improve the performance of my code.

I was able to narrow down the bottleneck to this method which does the header extraction from the string collected. Below is the most recent version of my method and is as optimized as I can get it (hopefully it will be better with your help):

```
    private List<string> GetHeader(List<string> FileLines)
        {
            List<string> headers = new List<string>();
            foreach (string line in FileLines)
            {
                string header = string.Empty;
                //Checks if there is a ':' and assumes that anything before that is the header except if it contains a date or a report id
                if(Regex.IsMatch(header, @"\w{2,4}[/\-]\w{2,3}[/\-]\w{2,4}", RegexOptions.Compiled) || Regex.IsMatch(header, @"^\w+, \w{2} \d{5}-{0,1}\d{0,5}", RegexOptions.Compiled))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                string nobrackets = Regex.Replace(line, @".*?\(.*?\)", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Compiled);
                if (line.IndexOf(':') != -1)
                {
                    string nobracks = Regex.Replace(line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(':') + 1), @"\(.*?\)", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Compiled);
                    if (nobracks.Split(' ').Length < 5 && nobracks.Length > 6)
                    {
                        headers.Add(line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(':') + 1));
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                //Checks if a string is larger then 5 words (not including brackets)
                if (!(nobrackets.Split(' ').Length < 5 && nobrackets.Length > 6))
                    continue;
                //Checks if the string is in all CAPS
                char[] letter = nobrackets.ToCharArray();

                if(letter.All(l => char.IsUpper(l))){
                    headers.Add(line);
                    continue;
                }

                //Checks if the string is 5 words or less
                string temp = Regex.Replace(line, @"\(.*?\)", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Compiled);
                if (temp.Split(' ').Length < 6)
                {
                    headers.Add(line);
                }

                //Checks for an all caps header embedded in a string
                bool caps = true;
                string[] word = line.Split(' ');
                int lastCapWordIndex = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < word.Length && caps; i++)
                {
                    char[] char_array = word[i].ToCharArray();

                    if (!letter.All(l => char.IsUpper(l)))
                    {
                        caps = false;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (caps)
                        lastCapWordIndex++;
                }
                if (lastCapWordIndex > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < lastCapWordIndex; i++)
                    {
                        header += " " + word[i];
                    }
                    headers.Add(header.Trim());
                    continue;
                }
            }

            //final check for string with less then 4 characters
            string[] tempH = headers.ToArray();
            headers = new List<string>();
            foreach (string h in tempH)
            {
                if (h.Length > 4)
                {
                    headers.Add(h);
                }
            }
            return headers;
        }
```

Comment: You have many things you can improve here,, most of them with a marginal impacts on performance but one thing catched my eyes: all those regex. Can't you create a single static regex and use it for them all?

Comment: It would be great, if you could provide some typical example lines and the expected output for each of them - both valid an invalid formats. Further we need to see, how you actually calls the method - in other words: we need some context in order to fully understand what you are doing.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I initially had one large regex which used OR to determine if it matched on case or another. But I found that it ran slower then using many smaller regex. Maybe I was doing something wrong? For example, I would have @"\w{2,4}[/\-]\w{2,3}[/\-]\w{2,4}|^\w+, \w{2} \d{5}-{0,1}\d{0,5}". But this ran a lot slower then making it two regex.

Comment: @HenrikHansen I have added an example to my question, please see the edit at the bottom. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: @k-Rocker: I don't see the change?

Comment: @k I see 5 regex (match/replace), few IndexOf and ToUpper comparisons. All of them should easily fit into one regex for matching and extracting groups. Should, of course, benchmark this but whole code should be a bunch of lines. I don't see usage but you might even yield return if caller performs extra processing (or just consume enumeration). This is also the perfect candidate for async enumerations (if you're targeting next C#)

Answer (score 3):

Let us first check the overall style of that method.

- The name of the method doesn't match the return type. The method is named `GetHeader` but it returns a `List<string>` hence `GetHeaders` would be a better name.
- Based on the [.NET Naming Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) method-parameters should be named using `camelCase` casing hence `FileLines` should be `fileLines`.
- If the type of the right-hand-side of an assignment is obvious one should use `var` instead of the concrete type.
- **Stick to one coding style**. Currently you are mixing styles in that method. **Sometimes** you place the opening braces `{` on the next line and sometimes you place it on the same line. **Sometimes** you use braces `{}` for single-line `if` statements and sometimes you don't. Omitting braces for single-line `if` statements should be avoided. Omitting barces can lead to hidden and therefor hard to find bugs.

---

Now let's dig into the code.

This

> ```
> //Checks if there is a ':' and assumes that anything before that is the header except if it contains a date or a report id
> if(Regex.IsMatch(header, @"\w{2,4}[/\-]\w{2,3}[/\-]\w{2,4}", RegexOptions.Compiled) || Regex.IsMatch(header, @"^\w+, \w{2}\d{5}-{0,1}\d{0,5}", RegexOptions.Compiled))
> {
>     continue;
> }
> ```

can be removed completely because it will always evaluate to `false`.

---

The regexes you use for replacements and matching should be extracted to `private static` fields like e.g

```
private static Regex noBracketsRegex = new Regex(@".*?\(.*?\)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

and used like so

```
string nobrackets = noBracketsRegex.Replace(line, string.Empty);
```

---

This

> ```
> string nobrackets = Regex.Replace(line, @".*?\(.*?\)", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Compiled);
> if (line.IndexOf(':') != -1)
> {
>     string nobracks = Regex.Replace(line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(':') + 1), @"\(.*?\)", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Compiled);
>     if (nobracks.Split(' ').Length < 5 && nobracks.Length > 6)
>     {
>         headers.Add(line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(':') + 1));
>         continue;
>     }
> }
>
> //Checks if a string is larger then 5 words (not including brackets)
> if (!(nobrackets.Split(' ').Length < 5 && nobrackets.Length > 6))
>     continue;
> ```

should be reorderd. You do the `Regex.Replace()` althought it could be possible that the most inner `if` condition could be `true`. You should store the result of `line.IndexOf(':')` in a variable otherwise if `line` contains a `:` you are calling `IndexOf()` twice and if the most inner `if` returns `true` you call it three times. Switching the most inner condition to evaluating the fastest condition should be done as well.

---

This

> ```
> string[] word = line.Split(' ');
> ```

should be renamed to `words`.

---

This

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < word.Length && caps; i++)
> {
>     char[] char_array = word[i].ToCharArray();
>
>     if (!letter.All(l => char.IsUpper(l)))
>     {
>         caps = false;
>         continue;
>     }
>     if (caps)
>         lastCapWordIndex++;
> }
> ```

doesn't buy you anything. You already checked `letter.All(l => char.IsUpper(l))` some lines above and if it returned `true` you `continue;` the moste outer loop. Hence it will return in this loop always `true` hence `lastCapWordIndex` will always be `0`. In addition a simple `break;` would be sufficiant because looping condition checks for `caps` being `true`.

The following

> ```
> if (lastCapWordIndex > 0)
> {
>     for (int i = 0; i < lastCapWordIndex; i++)
>     {
>         header += " " + word[i];
>     }
>     headers.Add(header.Trim());
>     continue;
> }
> ```

can be removed as well because `lastCapWordIndex` won't ever be `true` like stated above.

---

This

> ```
> //final check for string with less then 4 characters
> string[] tempH = headers.ToArray();
> headers = new List<string>();
> foreach (string h in tempH)
> {
>     if (h.Length > 4)
>     {
>         headers.Add(h);
>     }
> }
> return headers;
> ```

can be simplified by using a little bit of Linq like so

```
return new List<string>(headers.Where(s => s.Length > 4));
```

In addition the comment you placed above is lying because you check for strings which are less then 5 characters.

---

Implementing the mentioned points will lead to

```
private static Regex noBracketsRegex = new Regex(@".*?\(.*?\)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
private static Regex noBracksRegex = new Regex(@"\(.*?\)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
private List<string> GetHeaders(List<string> fileLines)
{
    var headers = new List<string>();
    foreach (string line in fileLines)
    {
        string header = string.Empty;

        int colonIndex = line.IndexOf(':');
        if (colonIndex != -1)
        {
            string nobracks = noBracksRegex.Replace(line.Substring(0, colonIndex + 1), string.Empty);
            if (nobracks.Length > 6 && nobracks.Split(' ').Length < 5)
            {
                headers.Add(line.Substring(0, colonIndex + 1));
                continue;
            }
        }

        string removedBracketsLine = noBracketsRegex.Replace(line, string.Empty);
        //Checks if a string is larger then 5 words (not including brackets)
        if (!(removedBracketsLine.Length > 6 && removedBracketsLine.Split(' ').Length < 5))
        {
            continue;
        }

        //Checks if the string is in all CAPS
        char[] letters = removedBracketsLine.ToCharArray();
        if (letters.All(l => char.IsUpper(l)))
        {
            headers.Add(line);
            continue;
        }

        //Checks if the string is 5 words or less
        string temp = noBracksRegex.Replace(line, string.Empty);
        if (temp.Split(' ').Length < 6)
        {
            headers.Add(line);
        }

    }
    return new List<string>(headers.Where(s => s.Length > 4));
}
```

The naming of the `Regex` could use a facelift but you should do it yourself because you know the meaning of them.